# Share a shared calendar OR automatically copy all events to one calendar

Tags: google-workspace, google-calendar

I have an iCal format calendar that's generated by my employment scheduling software. I have that calendar imported into my Google Calendar, and it works very well. However, I want to be able to share my free/busy info (in the form of an HTML embed).

I have the HTML embed working fine for all my personal calendars, but I can't get it working with my work calendar. I can't change settings on the work calendar iCal side, and Google Calendar doesn't seem to have any options for setting sharing on imported calendars like that. (In the calendar settings, it says that `Anyone can: see nothing`, `You can: see all event details`).

The shared calendar *is* added to the HTML embed, but if anyone goes to it, that calendar doesn't show up, and there's some red text at the top saying `Events from one or more calendars could not be shown here because you do not have the permission to view them.`

I can see two ways to fix this:

1. Either figure out a way to make my work calendar public from my Google Calendar account (i.e. without any access to permission settings in the work scheduling system)

OR

1. Figure out a way to automatically copy events from the shared work calendar to a local calendar (local == a calendar on *my* Google Account). I don't want to have to manually add/copy events to a calendar.

Is there a way to do either of these?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this IFTTT recipe](https://ifttt.com/recipes/4927-merge-google-calendars-in-a-single-one) to automatically copy new events from one calendar to another.

Comment: IFTTT recipe no longer works because google has discontinued XML feeds for calendars.